# How to delete certain k entries that belong to same group in pandas e.g. balance classes?

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have the following distribution of labels

```
Lbl
0    10451
1     1481
dtype: int64
```

How do I balance labels out? e.g picking only 1481 of 0s?

Given dataframe to be

```
index | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | Lbl
```

Thank you

EDIT:
Adding a picture to address the issue discussed in the answer:
[image]

I get the above ^^ for this code

```
print(table_train[:5])
table_train = table_train.groupby('Lbl').apply(lambda x : x.sample(1481)).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
print(table_train[:5])
```

Comment: so you want to downsample ?

Comment: @WeNYoBen I guess in a sense? I want to drop all values but 1481 for a label 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `sample` after `groupby`

```
df.groupby('Label').apply(lambda x : x.sample(1481)).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
```

Comment: I am not sure why but after running this command I have another index added with label Label. So now I have two same-named columns -- index Label and column Label...

Comment: I try to count later on result by
table_train.groupby('Label").size()
and i get 
ValueError: 'Label' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.

Comment: @YohanRoth using reset_index remove the addtional index

Comment: throws error "ValueError: cannot insert Label, already exists" when i do  table_train.reset_index()

Comment: @YohanRoth did you check my update method ? you should add drop=True

Comment: Yeah, i checked, tried. But it does not remove index...I still have ValueError: 'Lbl' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.

Comment: @YohanRoth `reset_index(level=0,drop=True)` change level=1 to level=0